# React navigation v5 slow because rerenders current screen before opening drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm working on a bigger app and have some lag when opening the drawer. It takes about *1 second* for the drawer animation to begin.
I looked into it with *react profiler* and saw that **the drawer is rendered and the current screen is rerendered before the drawer opens**. This makes things feeling slow, I would not suspect the current screen to rerender.
Here is how my *pseudo* navigation stack looks topdown:

```
//Toplevel
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator();
<NavigationContainer ref={navRef} theme={navTheme} linking={linking}>
  <RootStack.Navigator>
    {loggedIn ? (
      <RootStack.Screen component={inBetweenComponent} /> // => calls drawer
    ) : (
      // auth screen
    )}
  </RootStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

```
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
  const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
  const route = useRoute();
  const activeRoute = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route);

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} activeRoute={activeRoute} />}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsNavigator} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Conversations" component={ConversationsNavigator} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>

}
```

```
const DrawerContent = ({ activeRoute }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView>
      <TouchableNative onPress={goToNotifications} >..some text...</TouchableNative>
      <TouchableNative onPress={goToConversations} >..some text...</TouchableNative>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  )
}
```

```
const NotificationsNavigator = ({ navigation }) => {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerLeft: () => <HeaderLeft navigation={navigation} />, // -> contains open drawer button
      }}
      initialRouteName="Notifications"
    >
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```
const HeaderLeft = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const openNavigation = () => {
    navigation.openDrawer();
  };

  <TouchableNative /*someicon*/ onPress={openNavigator} />
```

I would like to know:

1. Is it normal that the current active screen rerenders before the drawer opens?
2. If normal, Is there any way around rerendering the current active screen? I tried a solution with useMemo + areEqual function with isDrawerOpen (useIsDrawerOpen) send from the parent. But that is not consistent and often gives wrong or undefined values.
3. Any other pointers to why this stack might be slow are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your screen is re-rendering when you open the drawer is because you're defining the drawer in the `DrawerNavigator` component.

This means every time React Navigation wants to find the drawer is has to reload not only the current screen, but *every screen in the drawer*.

Moving `const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();` outside of DrawerNavigator should solve your problem.

Comment: This was definitely wrong on my part and I made this mistake in the drawer and every Stack navigator aswell. So I was exited to fix it everywhere. Sadly, the result stays the same. The current screen rerenders when opening the drawer.. :/

Comment: In the end, the cache layer I called InBetweenComponent in my code example had a useEffect that was triggerd on (almost) every tap. This and your answer were both wrong in my setup. Thanks for the help, my app is buttery smooth now.